# Проблема при добавлении элемента appendChild

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь добавить элемент, таким образом:

```
var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
script_tag.setAttribute("src",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js");

(document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
```

И всё получается отлично.

Когда же я пытаюсь добавить ниже `Bootstrap`, точно таким же образом, то постоянно получаю ошибку:

> Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included
>   before Bootstrap's JavaScript.

То есть:

```
var bootstrap_script = document.createElement('script');
bootstrap_script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
bootstrap_script.setAttribute("src", 
  "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js")

(document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).append(bootstrap_script);
```

На практике же, последовательность соблюдена нормально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать правильно ?

Comment: Возможно, это происходит потому что ваш скрипт с `jQuery` еще не успел загрузиться. Попробуйте добавить `bootstrap` в событии `onload` скрипта `script_tag.onload = function(){...}`.